# Transfer a method to another method

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new here and I have a doubt. It is possible to transfer a method to another method?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void c_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Transfer OK!!!");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // c_Click ????? ------> button1_Click  
}
```

By clicking on Button2, via code is included c_Click the content within the button1.
Finally, clicking on button1, I need to bring up the "Transfer OK" message. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to attach `c_Click` as an event handler to `button1.Click` (in addition to the usual `button1_Click`)?

Comment: Thank you all. I do not want to run "PerformClick ()" or anything similar. Basically, it would delete the content of the button1_Click and include C_Click content within the button1_Click.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Default Message");
    c.PerformClick();
}

private void c_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Transfer OK!!!");  
}
```

[Button.PerformClick Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx) used to call button click event in any method

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this inside your button2_Click:

```
button1.PerformClick();

or 

c_Click(sender, e);
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I want to transfer. Clicking on button1, I need to bring up the "Transfer OK" message.

Comment: you want single event handler for multiple button ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Clicking on button1, I need to bring up the "Transfer OK" message.
Button2 will have code that will perform the deletion of button1 content and will include the contents of C_Click event. I guess it's something using "Delegates" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know if I understand your question but based on your comments:

> I do not want to run "PerformClick ()" or anything similar. Basically,
> it would delete the content of the button1_Click and include C_Click
> content within the button1_Click.
>
> Clicking on button1, I need to bring up the "Transfer OK" message.
> Button2 will have code that will perform the deletion of button1
> content and will include the contents of C_Click event. I guess it's
> something using "Delegates" or similar.

You're probably not using the word "Content" in the Windows Forms sense of the word. What I get from that is that when you click button2, you want button1 to start acting like the c_Click button, correct?

If I get you correctly you need to simply remove button1's EventHandler for button1_Click and replace it with c_Click, like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void c_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Transfer OK!!!");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // c_Click ????? ------> button1_Click 
    button1.Click -= new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    button1.Click +=new EventHandler(c_Click);
}
```

So that after you click button2, the next time you click on button1, it will do c_Click() instead of button1_Click()